# Python twitter function use for a list

Tags: python

New to python because I found something helpful.

I use the code for [here](https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass
```

I would like to use the function in a list of usernames I have. However some user names don't exist so I receive the following error:

```
TweepError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist.', u'code': 34}]
```

As my result my code stops.

What can I add in order to catch the username name which have the problem and the code doesn't stop but go to the next user name and see at the end which user names don't exist?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

   for x in range(0, len(df.index)):
       get_all_tweets(df.name[x])
```

I used this:

```
from tweepy.error import TweepError
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    #get_all_tweets(df.twitter_username[1])

   for x in range(0, len(df.index)):
       try:
           get_all_tweets(df.name[x])
           print x
       catch TweepError:
           pass  # which means "do nothing"
           print("Problem with username {}".format(df.name[x]))
```

but in catch I see in the warning that it is invalid syntax. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the exception using try-catch:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

   for x in range(0, len(df.index)):
       try:
           get_all_tweets(df.name[x])
       except TweepError:
           pass  # which means "do nothing"
```

Alternatively you can handle the exception in some other way, e.g. instead of "pass" do:

```
print("Problem with username {}".format(df.name[x]))
```

Of course, you'll need to have TweepError imported first:

```
from tweepy.error import TweepError
```

Comment: thank you I have tried to use it. It seems to me right but when I receive that catch has invalid systax. I have updated the code in the code at the end. Any idea why is invalid?

Comment: Found it. Not catch but expect in python